# Is it necessary to add an "android_assets" folder to my app's main?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, css

I've finished making an app with HTML, CSS, and JS files, all of which I've stored in the 'assets' folder of Android Studio.

The app runs without crashing, but only this screen appears:

[Empty app screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WLRy.png)

I've tried implementing each of the following file paths:

1. webView.loadUrl("file:///assets/menu.html");
2. webView.loadUrl("menu.html");

Neither of them work.

I've read that it's ideal to create a new folder in 'main' and call it 'android_assets' and then name the file path ("file:///android_assets/menu.html"); but I don't want to inadvertently create more problems in my code.

Should I create the 'android_assets' folder? Is there anything I'd risk in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.
Ensure your assets path is: `assets/foldersIfAny/index.html`

2.
Then use this:
`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/foldersIfAny/index.html");`